# register a repository conditionally in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to register a powershell repository in the following manner:

```
if((Get-PSRepository -Name $artifactory.Key.ToString().Trim()) -eq $null)
{
        #register the repository if not found
        $Location = "$($ConfigInfo.ArtifactoryCredentials.ArtifactoryServer.ToString().Trim())/$($artifactory.Value.ToString().Trim())"

        Write-Host "Registering repositories $($Location)" -ForegroundColor Cyan

        Register-PSRepository -Name $artifactory.Key.ToString().Trim() -SourceLocation $Location `
                                                                       -PublishLocation $Location `
                                                                       -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Verbose
}
```

It seems that the condition checking is not valid because the code steps into the if block with the following error:

```
PackageManagement\Get-PackageSource : Unable to find repository
```

Getting into the if block is valid, but it enter with an error, which I would like to suppress

How do I check if repo is found or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just negate the condition using ! Operator and add erroraction to ignore:

```
if(!(Get-PSRepository -Name $artifactory.Key.ToString().Trim() -ErrorAction Ignore ))
```

Comment: Thanks! you can even upvote the answer to increase its awareness your clicking ^ looking button.